# Why pandas.Series.tolist() is faster than pandas.Series.iat[]?

Tags: python, pandas, series

For example, we use the following Series object :

```
mySeries = pd.Series( range(0,20,2), index=range(1,11), name='col')
```

What is the proper way to access a value element ?

I would say `mySeries.iat[5]` or `mySeries.at[5]` depending we use position or index.

But I found that `mySeries.tolist()[5]` is 3 or 4 time faster than `mySeries.iat[5]` which is faster than `mySeries.at[5]`. ("loc" and "iloc" are even worse.)

It surprises me. What is the advantage of "iat" and "at" ?

Answer (score 2):

Because test short list from small Series, so converting to list and indexing is really fast:

```
mySeries = pd.Series( range(0,20,2), index=range(1,11), name='col')


%timeit mySeries.iat[5]
3.61 µs ± 261 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit mySeries.at[5]
5.11 µs ± 242 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit mySeries.tolist()
1.58 µs ± 78.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit mySeries.tolist()[5]
1.63 µs ± 141 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

If 1M values it is slow, because bottleneck is converting to list:

```
mySeries = pd.Series( range(0,2000000,2),  name='col')


%timeit mySeries.iat[5]
3.46 µs ± 72.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit mySeries.at[5]
4.74 µs ± 38.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit mySeries.tolist()
40.2 ms ± 618 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit mySeries.tolist()[5]
40.3 ms ± 517 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: It totally makes sense. since pandas is done for large datasets. I expected that converting to list would be the bottleneck in any case. Anyway, thank you.